# With Ehcache and spring what happens if a load balanced server become unavailable?

Tags: spring, load-balancing, ehcache

I'm working on a web app where Ehcache is deployed. This app is load balanced between multiple servers. The app is installed on each server and when a user accesses the app he/she is redirected to one of the load balanced servers.

Is my understanding of the following correct? If a user makes a request for a key and it's annotated with `@Cacheable` a check is made for the value in the Ehcache store. If the key is in the store then its value is returned from Ehcache, if the key is not in the store then the key and its value is added to the store and its value is returned. If one of the load balanced servers becomes unavailable and the user requests a value which has already been cached in the now-unavailable server then this new value will be added to the cache store and returned to the user as described above.

There is no risk of the user requesting a key which is not available, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by *a key which is not available*.

Essentially, [Spring caching abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/index.html#cache) works more or less as you described. Spring delegates the actual caching business to the configured caching library. In your case, this is ehcache.

If you have one cache per node, each node will have its copy of the data. If one server goes down and the user requests something that is not yet in this server's store, it will be put in that node's store as you described.

If you have a distributed cache, then the fact that the server goes down is meaningless with regards to your question:  you cached data will still available from the other node.

In any case, `Cacheable` tries to retrieve the value from the cache before calling the method and returns it directly in case of cache hit. In case of a cache miss, the method is executed and its result is stored in the cache.